# How do I force page reload in a link with hash sign?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link with hash sign:

[href="/#something"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277190/how-do-i-force-page-reload-in-a-link-with-hash-sign/#something)

How do I enable page reload when its clicked?

Is it only possible with js?

Comment: You can add a random parameter like this: https://stackoverflow.com/?parameter=<random_something>#something This will force a reload.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen to the HashChangeEvent and add a query param (like a timestamp) to the location search object:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    var dstringquery = `d=${new Date().getTime()}`;
    location.search = location.search.length === 0 ?  dstringquery : (location.search + '&' + dstringquery);
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

Comment: The comment from KIKO software is a simplier and working solution to my question, so I didn't try yours, but thank you anyway!