# Javascript redirect and on success call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

on my web page I have google maps (`buy.html`), where user clicks on any continent. If he clicks on Asia I hide div with world map and show new map (new div with `id="asia"`) and my url now looking like this `buy.html#asia`

In footer, I have menu with name of continent, and when user click on name of any continent I need to redirect him to that selected continent (`buy.html#asia` or `buy.html#africa` or `buy.html#australia` etc.)

First I try everything fix only in html

```
<a href="buy.html#australia">Australia</a>
<a href="buy.html#asia">Asia</a>
<a href="buy.html#africa">Africa</a>
```

But this redirect me to `buy.html#australia` but showing me full map not only Australia

I try this second, in my html I call function like this

```
<a href="" onclick="changeState('Australia');">Australia</a>
<a href="" onclick="changeState('Asia');">Asia</a>
<a href="" onclick="changeState('Africa');">Africa</a>
```

and this is how I try to make this from .js Idea was, on click redirect to `buy.html` and on success call new function `show_country(name)`. This function working when I click on the map, so I think code it's not necessary here. If someone needs to see this code for this function I will post it here

```
function changeState(name){
document.location.href = "domein.com/buy.html";
//i'm stuck here, how to add success and call this function on success 
show_country(name)
};
```

Here document.location.href not working for me, and I don't know how to, in this case, add success.

I hope you understand my question

Comment: Does it get to function changeState(name)?

Comment: Did you try `document.location.href = http://domein.com/buy.html` ?

Comment: can you try `window.location.hash = name;` inside your change state function

Comment: @grumpy  yes, function changeState(name) is executed but not showing continent

Comment: @rach8garg yes i try, and not change my location

Comment: try to give window.location.href='domein.com/buy.html#'+name

Comment: i edited my comment, try the re direction with http://. Also its better not to redirect. because after redirecting it will not call show_country function unless you add it inside window.onload

Comment: @AswinRamesh if I change to window.location.hash I get domein.com/buy.html#domein.com/buy.html

Comment: name parameter of `changeState` return the only the name(like asia) right? then how come `domein.com/buy.html#domein.com/buy.html`?

Comment: @AswinRamesh because window.location.href return me full URL

Comment: change your html like this: 
<a href="#australia" onclick="changeState('Australia');">Australia</a>

and then update your function like this:

function changeState(name){
    show_country(name)
};

Comment: Check the answer below. Hope it helps @Arter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember [a post I answered few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48277554/1171217) looking like yours. You have to use a "hash change" handler to do what you want:

Use this links in your menu:

```
<a href="buy.html#australia">Australia</a>
<a href="buy.html#asia">Asia</a>
<a href="buy.html#africa">Africa</a>
```

And add this script at the end of your buy.html page:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
     if (location.hash.startsWith("#")) {
        show_country(decodeURI(location.hash).substring(1));
     }
}

//bind handler for next clicks
window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;

//on page load call to init the right view
locationHashChanged();
```

Comment: This add me URL like this domein.com#Africa insed of domein.com/buy.html#Africa

Comment: Answer edited. Add the script at the end of buy.html, and replace links as above.

Comment: Ok, this work if im on buy.html but if im on any another page and click in footer, this redirect me again on buy.html but in url is domein.com/buy.html#Africa etc

Comment: Sorry but can you explain us how many "from" pages do you have ? and what should they do when you click on link items ?

Comment: I have same foter on all page. Index.html, about.html, product.html etc. In footer i have menu with continent name. And now, if im on any of this page i need to have options when i click on continent name, redirect me to buy.html#continentName

Comment: Ok, so a link with "buy.html#asia" from any page will always redirect to the buy.html page and will display the Asia continent. You have to change all links in all page to point to buy.html. Right ? (I think that I answered that way)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163393/discussion-between-arter-and-okoch).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with your first method and script, and also add the common class "map" for all map div.

HTML Code:

```
<a href="buy.html#australia">Australia</a>
<a href="buy.html#asia">Asia</a>
<a href="buy.html#africa">Africa</a>
```

Script :

```
<script>
$(function () {
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
var res = url.split("#");
var id = res[1];
$(".map").css("display", "none");
$("#"+id).css("display", "block");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using HTML bookmarks. 
HTML bookmarks are used to allow readers to jump to specific parts of a Web page. In your case its showing maps.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    let activeMap = Boolean(document.location.hash) ? document.location.hash : "#Asia";
 console.log(activeMap);
    document.querySelector(activeMap).style.display = "block";
}

function changeState(name){
    console.log("I am in", name);
    let maps = document.querySelectorAll(".map");
    for(let i=0; i < maps.length; i++){
        maps[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.querySelector("#"+name).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.map{display: none};
```

```html
<div id="Australia" class="map">Australia</div>

<div id="Africa" class="map">Africa</div>

<div id="Asia" class="map">Asia</div>


<a href="#Australia" onclick="changeState('Australia');">Australia</a> |
<a href="#Africa" onclick="changeState('Africa');">Africa</a> |
<a href="#Asia" onclick="changeState('Asia');">Asia</a>
```